# How to scan and return a set of words with specific characters in them in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to have a match function that returns words with periods or dashes in them (and possibly a growing list). I was thinking:

```
b="here a.b are things a.d long-thing others".scan(/\.|-/)
```

which could return an array of `["a.b","a.d","long-thing"]` rather than `[".",".","-"]`.

How would I tell scan to return the whole word?

Comment: more like a regexp question than ruby related. `\w+[.-]\w+`

Comment: @radubogdan true -  adjusted

Comment: I believe you wanted `/\w(?:[.-]\w+)*)/`.

Comment: This is answered in the [Regexp documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html). Please take the time to research as it's very elementary and core to regular expressions and is well covered in multiple places. http://rubular.com, http://regexr.com and https://www.regex101.com all make it easy to learn. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the word characters into your regexp too. For example by adding `\w+` to the regexp which means: At least one word character:

```
b = "here a.b are things a.d long-thing others"
b.scan(/\w+[.-]\w+/)
#=> ["a.b", "a.d", "long-thing"]
```

Comment: Might I suggest the regular expression `/\w+[.-]\w+/` instead?

Comment: Well your idea is long in the comment section under the question, but w/e.

Comment: @spickermann And btw, the only thing that must be escaped in square brackets is a square bracket.

Comment: hmm... so this works for the question but the word boundary causes words like 'a.o.c' to get returned as 'a.o' rather than returned as 'a.o.c' - is there any way to tell the word boundary to ONLY be a space. Or to handle a word like 'a.c-things'. (btw, I hate when people do what I do - sorry)

Comment: Interesting @timpone, that's a change of requirement.

Comment: agreed  - will just do as a separate question

Answer (score 4):

For your question and your updated question and your future updated question, I'd use something like split and grep regexp.

**Regexp version (with condition to not have `.` or `-` at the end:**

```
"here a.b are things a.d long-thing others a.b.c a.c-things".scan(/\S+[.-]\S+/)
```

**#split, #select and regexp**

```
 s = "here a.b are things a.d long-thing others a.b.c a.c-things"
 s.split(" ").select { |el| el[/[.-]/] }
```

**#split, #select, #include?**

```
 s.split(" ").select { |el| el.include?(".") || el.include?("-") }
```

Last one can be modified by sending `el` to a function where you decide all the logic. Right now it catches a lot of junk, but that's for you to fix.

Regards

Comment: I like the Regexp version.

Comment: Might I suggest `\S` instead of `[^ ]`? `\S` includes all non-whitespace characters.

Comment: Both versions use Regex and Ruby.  Also, may I suggest to get rid of that scroll bar in code by reducing number of chars on that line - may be declare a variable `s="here a.b ....."`

Comment: Well that's true @WandMaker. What I meant in with "ruby version" was more an idiomatic approach.

Comment: There's nothing unidiomatic about `String#scan`. I think it's much more idiomatic to solve the problem with a single, simple regex than with `split` and `select`. Also, why not `/\S+[.-]\S+/`? (P.S. I upvoted your answer; I don't want you to think I'm nitpicking just to be contrary—it's a good answer!)

Comment: Well I agree with `\S+` it's just that I forgot to change the last part. Also I updated the answer and I got rid of the "idiomatic" thingy. It was my personal favourite because you can see the logic in it and it's more natural than reading a bunch of characters in a scan (but this is a very simple scan). This is just my personal opinion. I don't think you're nitpicking, I appreciate your intervention.