# How to scan for substrings with specific characters in them

Tags: ruby, regex

This is a follow-up to this question. [How to scan and return a set of words with specific characters in them in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319032/how-to-scan-and-return-a-set-of-words-with-specific-characters-in-them-in-ruby)

We want to scan for words starting with a certain set of letters and then return them in an array. Something like this:

```
 b="h ARCabc s and other ARC12".scan(/\w+ARC*\w+/)
```

and get back:

```
["ARCabc","ARC12"]
```

How would I do this (and I know this is very similar to what I asked yesterday)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the following regex:

```
\bARC\w*\b
```

or (to exclude underscores from matching)

```
\bARC[[:alnum:]]*\b
```

See [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/zIFHm7wQXp)

The regex matches:

- `\b` - a word boundary (`ARC` at the start of a word only)
- `ARC` - a fixed sequence of characters
- `\w*` - 0 or more letter, digits or underscores. **NOTE**: if you only want to limit the matches to letters and digits, replace this `\w*` with  `[[:alnum:]]*`.
- `\b` - end of word (trailing) boundary.

See [IDEONE demo here](http://ideone.com/Ckdjt1) (output: `ARCabc` and `ARC12`).

**NOTE2**: If you plan to match Unicode strings, consider using either of the following regexps:

- `\bARC\p{Word}*\b` - this variation will match words with underscores after `ARC`
- `\bARC[\p{L}\p{M}\d]*\b` - this regex will match words that only have digits and Unicode letters after `ARC`.

Answer (score 1):

For good readability, you could split the string into words and then select the ones you want:

```
str = "h ARCabc s and other ARC12"
target = "ARC"

str.split.select { |w| w.include?(target) }
  #=> ["ARCabc", "ARC12"]
```

If the words must begin with `target`:

```
str.split.select { |w| w.start_with?(target) }
```